# How do I specify multiple data sets to an XY-scatter plot using the Google Chart API?

Tags: google-visualization

Why doesn't this Google Chart API URL render both data sets on this XY scatter plot?

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lxy&chd=t:10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200|0.10,0.23,0.33,0.44,0.56,0.66,0.79,0.90,0.99,1.12,1.22,1.33,1.44,1.56,1.68,1.79,1.90,2.02,2.12,2.22|0.28,0.56,0.85,1.12,1.42,1.68,1.97,2.26,2.54,2.84,3.12,3.40,3.84,4.10,4.53,4.80,5.45,6.02,6.40,6.80&chco=3072F3,ff0000,00aaaa&chls=2,4,1&chs=320x240&chds=0,201,0,7&chm=s,FF0000,0,-1,5|s,0000ff,1,-1,5|s,00aa00,2,-1,5
```

I've read the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) over and over again, and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it actually does render both data sets, but you can only se one of them because there's only one scale on the y axis. (In other words, 0.10 is too small to show.)

And, you should really be using percentages. 100 is the highest accepted value:

> Where chart data string consists of positive floating point numbers from zero (0.0) to one hundred (100.0)

Answer (score 2):

First a point of clarification. You talk about a "XY scatter plot", but these are actually 2 distinct chart types in the Google Chart API. Your URL refers to cht=lxy parameter which is an [XY line chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/types.html#line_charts).

The first problem with your URL is your data parameter (chd). Since it is an [XY line chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/types.html#line_charts), data sets must be defined in **pairs** but I see an odd number of data sets (3).

Christian D's response is incorrect. There is no percentage requirement.

You may be better off using a [wrapper API](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/web/useful-links-to-api-libraries) which abstracts away many of these ugly details.